# Docker error - The file was not found in the configured search path

Tags: docker, liquibase

I am trying to user docker to run a liquibase update, but the way I have the volume mapping doesn't seem to work, it doesn't find a file on my local environment. Any ideas?

I run the following docker cmd:

```
docker run --rm --network host -v /home/richardmarais/Development/IdeaProjects/travellinck-javaee/corporateInterface/src/main/resources/db:/db \
liquibase/liquibase update \
--changelog-file=/db/local/changelog-local-master.xml \
--url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5431/pims" \
--username=postgres \
--password=password
```

and get:

```
####################################################
##   _     _             _ _                      ##
##  | |   (_)           (_) |                     ##
##  | |    _  __ _ _   _ _| |__   __ _ ___  ___   ##
##  | |   | |/ _` | | | | | '_ \ / _` / __|/ _ \  ##
##  | |___| | (_| | |_| | | |_) | (_| \__ \  __/  ##
##  \_____/_|\__, |\__,_|_|_.__/ \__,_|___/\___|  ##
##              | |                               ##
##              |_|                               ##
##                                                ## 
##  Get documentation at docs.liquibase.com       ##
##  Get certified courses at learn.liquibase.com  ## 
##                                                ##
####################################################
Starting Liquibase at 06:39:31 (version 4.25.1 #690 built at 2023-12-18 16:29+0000)
Liquibase Version: 4.25.1
Liquibase Open Source 4.25.1 by Liquibase
ERROR: Exception Details
ERROR: Exception Primary Class:  ChangeLogParseException
ERROR: Exception Primary Reason: The file /db/local/changelog-local-master.xml was not found in the configured search path:
    - /liquibase
    - /liquibase/changelog
    - /liquibase/classpath
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/liquibase-core.jar
    - /liquibase/lib
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/mariadb-java-client.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/jaybird.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/snowflake-jdbc.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/jcc.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/h2.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/commons-text.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/jaxb-runtime.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/liquibase-commercial.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/ojdbc8.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/jaxb-api.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/picocli.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/hsqldb.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/sqlite-jdbc.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/commons-collections4.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/commons-lang3.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/mssql-jdbc.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/opencsv.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/postgresql.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/snakeyaml.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/jaxb-core.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib
More locations can be added with the 'searchPath' parameter.
ERROR: Exception Primary Source: 4.25.1

Unexpected error running Liquibase: The file /db/local/changelog-local-master.xml was not found in the configured search path:
    - /liquibase
    - /liquibase/changelog
    - /liquibase/classpath
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/liquibase-core.jar
    - /liquibase/lib
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/mariadb-java-client.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/jaybird.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/snowflake-jdbc.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/jcc.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/h2.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/commons-text.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/jaxb-runtime.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/liquibase-commercial.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/ojdbc8.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/jaxb-api.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/picocli.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/hsqldb.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/sqlite-jdbc.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/commons-collections4.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/commons-lang3.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/mssql-jdbc.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/opencsv.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/postgresql.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/snakeyaml.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib/jaxb-core.jar
    - /liquibase/internal/lib
More locations can be added with the 'searchPath' parameter.
```

This is a file on my local os (Ubuntu):

```
/home/richardmarais/Development/IdeaProjects/travellinck-javaee/corporateInterface/src/main/resources/db/local/changelog-local-master.xml
```

Comment: It looks like Liquibase doesn't have significant [requirements](https://docs.liquibase.com/start/install/liquibase-requirements.html) beyond a JVM; can you download and run its CLI locally, without involving Docker at all?  Can your application framework embed Liquibase and run migrations on its own (Spring Boot can, for example)?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is a bit iffy, but it and the output you get seem to indicate that the search path https://docs.liquibase.com/parameters/search-path.html parameter is needed in addition to the file name.

Seems that it's now trying to search for a file called `/db/local/changelog-local-master.xml` from the default search paths, instead of using `/db/local/changelog-local-master.xml` filepath directly.

If you have verified that the file really exists in that location, try adding the path to search path with `--search-path /db/local/` and changing the `--changelog-file` to just `changelog-local-master.xml`.